# Deformation Retract of $I^2 - \{c_0\}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider $I^2 \setminus \{c_0\}$, unit square with the center point removed. Call this space $X$.
Consider $I^2$ with a small open disk removed about $c_0$ Call this space $Y$.
Instead of taking open disk in $Y$, take closed disk instead. Call this space $Z$.

Now, I want to construct a deformation retract from X to Y and deformation retract from X to Z. Let us say that interior of the disk is radially retracted (retraction is well-defined since the disk has $c_0$ removed). Now I have a little issue.

Intuitively, deformation retract from $X$ to $Z$ does not make sense; for any $p$ in the interior of the disk with $c_0$ removed, $p$ needs to land somewhere on $S^1$. However, $S^1$, which is the boundary of the disk, is removed and $p$ is “lost” where to go under the retraction. In this sense, deformation retract of $X$ to $Z$ is not well-defined.

**Question 1: Does this rule out the possibility of retraction/deformation retract from $X$ to $Z$?**

Now, let us investigate what happens if we embed $X, Y, Z$ in $I^2$. $X$ is open, $Y$ is closed, and $Z$ is open.

**Question 2: Under deformation retraction $r: X \rightarrow Y$, an open space is retracted to a closed space. Is thist he right thing?**

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Open and closed is not the right way to phrase things (there is no such thing as an open/closed space). What is true, for instance, is that there is no retraction of $Y$ onto $Z$ for the reason that $Y$ is *compact* whereas $Z$ is not. Of course $Y$ is compact because it is a closed subset of the compact $I^2$, but closedness is not the correct property to extract from this information. Note that $Y$ is a deformation retract of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Q1 : There does not exist a retraction from $X$ to $Z$.

Let $i : Z \to X$ denote inclusion. Assume there exists a retraction $r : X \to Z$. The map $R = ir : X \to X$ has the property $R(x) = x$ for $x \in Z$. Since $Z$ is Hausdorff, the set $\{ x \in X \mid R(x) = x \}$ is closed in $X$, thus it must contain $\overline Z = Y$. Thus for all $x \in Y \setminus Z$ we must have $x = R(x) = r(x) \in Z$, a contradiction.

Q2: As Tyrone comments, it does not make sense to call $X$ an *open space* and $Y$ a *closed space*.

Yes, $X$ is an open subspace of $I^2$ and $Y$ a closed  subspace of $I^2$, but that is completely irrelevant in this context. Points outside of $X$ and $Y$ do not play any role for maps $X \to Y$. The space $X$ is non-compact and $Y$ is compact, but that does not play a role either. The punctured closed disk is radially retracted to its boundary - this gives you the desired (strong) deformation retraction $r : X \to Y$.